# Weird top banner bug on mobile site

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button

See the top banner in this screenshot, looks like a bug to me.

[image]

Comment: It's sprites. It's always sprites. (on a serious note, this means you're on a Retina device that has auto zoom in browsers)